# Python psycopg2: Find all opened cursors

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I am working on application with postgreSQL and using psycopg2 to connect to the database.

1. Is there a way to check all opened cursors via connection.cursor()
2. When connection.cursor() is executed should a cursor be visible in the pg_cursors view?
3. Are cursors object created from psycopg the same as the cursors in postgres pg_cursors?

Comment: What's the reason that you want to find cursors and not connections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not that I know of.
2. & 3) No and yes.

No) A 'regular' cursor is a client side cursor and will not be seen.

Yes) If you use a 'named' cursor then it is a server side cursor that has been `DECLAREd`. For more information see [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor) and [Server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors)